# WSO2 API User Mangement

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have my own MySql database with users and roles.

***How to integrate with WSO2 so that a token can be generated from my MySql database?***

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+a+JDBC+User+Store

Answer (score 4):

If your database schema is not as wos2 IS schemas, you cannot integrate your DB directly. (you can check the DB scripts in the product to see the schema)

If your DB schema is compliant with wso2 IS then follow doc

1.https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/setup/changing-to-mysql/#! [IS 5.9 & upwards]
2.https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+a+JDBC+User+Store [IS5.7]

If it is not compliant then you have two options

1. Write custom userstore manager and connect your existing DB : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager
2. Export you users from your current DB to wso2 IS compliant DB. To export user wso2 provide options to use soap endpoint: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/develop/managing-users-and-roles-with-apis/#adduser or rest endpoint: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Is WSO2 IS and WSO2 AM same ?  What is the difference between WSO2 IS and WSO2 AM ?  I want to create custom user store manager and connect my existing DB. **Can I proceed with the above docs as I want to use WSO2 as an API Gateway using WSO2 API Manger.**

Comment: WSO2 IS is an identity provider and WSO2 AM is API manager. Both are different products but their underline structures were same as they both use the same kernel.  For user store-related stuffs you can use above doc as it is coming from the kernel or follow this doc space dedicated for AM https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductAdministration/ManagingUsersAndRoles/ManagingUserStores/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/